# What plane has the widest range in speed in which it can operate?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airspeed, stall, airplane

What propellor plane, other than planes with vertical takeoff capability, has the largest gap in speed between its slowest stall speed and its maximum airspeed? I am looking for a plane with a short take-off but also can go fast if needed or slow and fuel-efficient.

Comment: The SR-71 lands at 155 knots, and has a top speed of +1900 knots, giving a speed range of about 1750 knots.

Comment: Basically the fastest plane wins that *record* (since planes eventually land at very moderate speeds). So it will be the SR-71 or the Shuttle, depending on how you define a plane. Also kindly check [How do I ask a good question?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) It's better to ask questions that invite how and why.

Comment: @Xaddell: Hover over the tag, it says *"A heavier-than-air fixed-wing aircraft propelled by one or more engines."* The term [airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane) has nothing to do with the propulsive method, so an SR-71 and a 747 are as much planes as a Cessna.

Comment: @ymb1 Thank you for correcting that. I will revise the question.

Comment: @Xaddell: Same thing, it will still be whatever the fastest propeller plane is.

Comment: @Xaddell **Range** is the difference between v.max and v.min, so it's just the fastest plane question. Are you sure you want **range** and not **ratio** (v.max / v.min, division)?

Comment: @Xaddell: So you're asking what the *fastest STOL airplane* is? If yes, then I think it's easy to find out. There's also this: [Would a two-seat light fixed-wing aircraft with a landing speed of 20 knots and a top speed of 180 knots be technically possible?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65780/14897)

Comment: If you're looking for ratio, I think one of the answers here will help: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/would-a-two-seat-light-fixed-wing-aircaft-with-a-landing-speed-of-20-knots-and-a

Comment: @ymb1 yes that question is spot on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would a two-seat light fixed-wing aircraft with a landing speed of 20 knots and a top speed of 180 knots be technically possible?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/would-a-two-seat-light-fixed-wing-aircraft-with-a-landing-speed-of-20-knots-and)